# Magic link doesn't render in Network Profile

Tags: bug, network-profile, magic-links

Looking at a recent comment in my Network Profile I see that the regular link contained therein rendered properly (i.e. the link is hidden and the text is in blue) but the magic link does not:

[image: Screenshot of network profile]

When I look at the same comment in my profile for that site, both links render properly:

[image: Screenshot of local profile]

Thus, it seems to be a problem with the Network Profile.

Comment: @rob Isn't that a different issue? What I'm noting here is that a link *does* work, unless it's a magic link. You can see in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpTyK.png) that this is even if it is the exact same link.